# SQLite - Group Combine Columns Across Tables

Tags: sqlite

I am attempting to write a custom SQL report and I am very close. I just can't get the last bit figured out.

Basically, the report is going to end up showing unapproved software. Below is my almost working code. I am trying to put all computers and users in 1 field. I can get this working by itself, but just not sure how to group_concat it properly. Here is what I have:

```
select
    Applications.Name 'Application',
    Applications.Version 'Version',
    count(Computers.Name) 'Count',
    Applications.Uninstall 'Uninstall String',
    case
        WHEN Computers.CurrentUser = '' THEN group_concat(Computers.Name, ', ')
        ELSE Computers.Name || ' (' || Computers.CurrentUser || '), '
    END AS 'Computer/Users'
FROM Computers inner join Applications on Computers.ComputerID=Applications.ComputerID
where Applications.Name LIKE '%McAfee%'
group by Applications.Name
```

I believe my issue is with `ELSE Computers.Name || ' (' || Computers.CurrentUser || '), '` but I am just not sure how to group_concat, or something else.

It outputs:

```
+------------------------------------------+-------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|              "McAfee Agent"              | "5.0.5.658" | "334" | "MsiExec.exe /qn /norestart /X{265FA622-A254-49fb-B380-D9EF9ABFD32D}"  | "Computer1, Computer2, Computer3, Computer4, " |
+------------------------------------------+-------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| "McAfee Host Intrusion Prevention"       | "8.00.0000" | "129" | "MsiExec.exe /qn /norestart /X{D2B9C003-A3CD-44A0-9DE5-52FE986C03E5}"  | "Computer1 (Computer1\User1), "                |
| "McAfee Management of Native Encryption" | "4.0.0.84"  | "9"   | ""                                                                     | "Computer27 (DOMAIN\Userasdasd), "             |
| "McAfee VirusScan Enterprise"            | "8.8.09000" | "334" | "MsiExec.exe /qn /norestart /X{CE15D1B6-19B6-4D4D-8F43-CF5D2C3356FF}"  | "Computer1, Computer2, Computer3, Computer4, " |
+------------------------------------------+-------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

I am hoping to get Computer1 (User), Computer2 (User2), etc... I chopped off the list of computers as it is huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group_concat()` is applied to whatever you give it as parameter.

If you want to have the "Computer(User)" values concatenated, you have to write them inside the `group_concat()`:

```
group_concat(CASE WHEN Computers.CurrentUser = ''
                  THEN Computers.Name
                  ELSE Computers.Name || ' (' || Computers.CurrentUser || ')'
             END,
             ', ')
```